# Strange women and their strange ways of giving you phone numbers

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

While Bob was walking down the street one day, he met a wonderful woman that was attractive and smart and a great conversationalist.

After they had been chatting for a while the woman looked at her watch and quickly got up and scribbled something down while saying "I have to go, I'm running very late. Here's my phone number, if you know my name you can call me, otherwise don't bother."

This is what she wrote on the paper:

> 1.4- 2-2.2- 1.4- 2.3- 2-2.2- 1.4- 1-4. 2-2.2- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4-
>   4-1. 2-2.2- 1.4- 4.1- 2-2.2- 4.1- 2-2.2- 4-1. 2-2.2- 1.4-
>   2.3- 5- 2-2.2- 1.4- 2-2.2- 1.4- 4.1- 2-2.2- 2-3. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5.
>   1.4- 4-1. 2-2.2- 4-1. 2-2.2- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4-
>   4-1. 2-2.2- 1.4- 4.1- 2-2.2- 4.1- 2-2.2- 4-1. 2-2.2- 1.4-
>   2.3- 4.1- 2-2.2- 1.4- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 2-2.2- 2.3- 5.
>   1.4- 4-1. 2-2.2- 4-1. 2-2.2- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4-
>   5. 2-2.2- 3.2- 2-2.2- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5.
>   2.3- 2.3- 2-2.2- 4-1. 2-2.2- 3.2- 2-2.2- 2.3- 5- 2-2.2- 1.4- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 3-2.
>   5. 2-2.2- 3.2- 2-2.2- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5.
>   1.4- 4.1- 2-2.2- 1.4- 5. 2-2.2- 2.3- 2.3- 2-2.2- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 3.2- 2-2.2- 2.3- 2-2.2- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 3-2.
>   1-4. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5. 2-2.2- 2.3- 4.1- 2-2.2- 2.3- 5- 2-2.2- 1.4- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5. 2-2.2- 2.3- 5-
>   4-1. 2-2.2- 1.4- 4.1- 2-2.2- 4.1- 2-2.2- 4-1. 2-2.2- 1.4-
>   1-4. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5. 2-2.2- 2.3- 4.1- 2-2.2- 2.3- 5- 2-2.2- 1.4- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5. 2-2.2- 2.3- 5-
>   5. 2-2.2- 3.2- 2-2.2- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5.
>   2.3- 5- 2-2.2- 1.4- 2-2.2- 1.4- 4.1- 2-2.2- 2-3. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5.
>   1.4- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 3.2- 2-2.2- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5.
>   5. 2-2.2- 3.2- 2-2.2- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5.
>   5. 2-2.2- 3.2- 2-2.2- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5.
>   2.3- 1-4. 2-2.2- 2.3- 1.4- 2-2.2- 1.4- 2.3- 2-2.2- 2.3- 1.4-
>   5. 2-2.2- 3.2- 2-2.2- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5.
>   5. 2-2.2- 3.2- 2-2.2- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5.
>   1.4- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 3.2- 2-2.2- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5.
>   1.4- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 4-1. 2-2.2- 3.2- 2-2.2- 1.4- 2-2.2- 1.4- 3-2.
>   1.4- 4.1- 2-2.2- 1.4- 5. 2-2.2- 2.3- 2.3- 2-2.2- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 3.2- 2-2.2- 2.3- 2-2.2- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 3-2.
>   4-1. 2-2.2- 1.4- 4.1- 2-2.2- 4.1- 2-2.2- 4-1. 2-2.2- 1.4-
>   1.4- 4.1- 2-2.2- 1.4- 5. 2-2.2- 2.3- 2.3- 2-2.2- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 3.2- 2-2.2- 2.3- 2-2.2- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 3-2.
>   5. 2-2.2- 3.2- 2-2.2- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5.
>   1.4- 3-2. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 3.2- 2-2.2- 5. 2-2.2- 1.4- 5.

For obvious reasons, Bob was rather confused for a while. He realized that in their entire conversation she had never said her name.

All the same, he began trying to figure out the message she had written him. He was beginning to despair but then as he finished working out what she had written him, he immediately knew her name and called her number the first chance he got.

**What was her name?**

Comment: I love that she was running very late, and yet had time to write THAT on a piece of paper.

Comment: @DanRussell Bob told me she writes super fast.

Comment: Maybe she keeps a few copies of this always with her to find out intelligent guys.

Comment: This girl sounds difficult. Throw the piece of paper away.

Comment: Is this a new way of playing hard to get?

Comment: @kirkpatt I guess so. Poor Bob.

Comment: Mulva? Oh, oh Dolores!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Her name is

> Jenny

Her phone number is

> 867-5309

Because

> The message is in morse code, the numbers represent the number of `.`s and `-`s should be in that place.  E.g. `1.4-` = `.----`

The translated message is:

> .---- --..-- .---- ..--- --..-- .---- -.... --..-- ---.. --..-- .---- --..--
>  ----. --..-- .---- ....- --..-- ....- --..-- ----. --..-- .---- --..--
>  ..--- ----- --..-- .---- --..-- .---- ....- --..-- --... --..-- .---- ..... --..--
>  .---- ----. --..-- ----. --..-- ..... --..-- .---- ---.. --..-- .---- ---.. --..-- .---- --..--
>  ----. --..-- .---- ....- --..-- ....- --..-- ----. --..-- .---- --..--
>  ..--- ....- --..-- .---- ---.. --..-- .---- --..-- ..--- ..... --..--
>  .---- ----. --..-- ----. --..-- ..... --..-- .---- ---.. --..-- .---- ---.. --..-- .---- --..--
>  ..... --..-- ...-- --..-- ---.. --..-- .---- ..... --..--
>  ..--- ..--- --..-- ----. --..-- ...-- --..-- ..--- ----- --..-- .---- ..... --..-- .---- ---.. --..--
>  ..... --..-- ...-- --..-- ---.. --..-- .---- ..... --..--
>  .---- ....- --..-- .---- ..... --..-- ..--- ..--- --..-- ..... --..-- .---- ...-- --..-- ..--- --..-- ..... --..-- .---- ---.. --..--
>  -.... --..-- .---- ..... --..-- ..--- ....- --..-- ..--- ----- --..-- .---- ---.. --..-- .---- ..... --..-- ..--- ----- --..--
>  ----. --..-- .---- ....- --..-- ....- --..-- ----. --..-- .---- --..--
>  -.... --..-- .---- ..... --..-- ..--- ....- --..-- ..--- ----- --..-- .---- ---.. --..-- .---- ..... --..-- ..--- ----- --..--
>  ..... --..-- ...-- --..-- ---.. --..-- .---- ..... --..--
>  ..--- ----- --..-- .---- --..-- .---- ....- --..-- --... --..-- .---- ..... --..--
>  .---- ---.. --..-- .---- ..... --..-- .---- ...-- --..-- ..... --..-- .---- ..... --..--
>  ..... --..-- ...-- --..-- ---.. --..-- .---- ..... --..--
>  ..... --..-- ...-- --..-- ---.. --..-- .---- ..... --..--
>  ..--- -.... --..-- ..--- .---- --..-- .---- ..--- --..-- ..--- .---- --..--
>  ..... --..-- ...-- --..-- ---.. --..-- .---- ..... --..--
>  ..... --..-- ...-- --..-- ---.. --..-- .---- ..... --..--
>  .---- ---.. --..-- .---- ..... --..-- .---- ...-- --..-- ..... --..-- .---- ..... --..--
>  .---- ..... --..-- .---- ----. --..-- ...-- --..-- .---- --..-- .---- ---.. --..--
>  .---- ....- --..-- .---- ..... --..-- ..--- ..--- --..-- ..... --..-- .---- ...-- --..-- ..--- --..-- ..... --..-- .---- ---.. --..--
>  ----. --..-- .---- ....- --..-- ....- --..-- ----. --..-- .---- --..--
>  .---- ....- --..-- .---- ..... --..-- ..--- ..--- --..-- ..... --..-- .---- ...-- --..-- ..--- --..-- ..... --..-- .---- ---.. --..--
>  ..... --..-- ...-- --..-- ---.. --..-- .---- ..... --..--
>  .---- ---.. --..-- .---- ..... --..-- .---- ...-- --..-- ..... --..-- .---- .....

Which, converted to plain text is:

> 1,12,16,8,1,9,14,4,9,1,20,1,14,7,15,19,9,5,18,18,1,9,14,4,9,1,24,18,1,25,19,9,5,18,18,1,5,3,8,15,22,9,3,20,15,18,5,3,8,15,14,15,22,5,13,2,5,18,6,15,24,20,18,15,20,9,14,4,9,1,6,15,24,20,18,15,20,5,3,8,15,20,1,14,7,15,18,15,13,5,15,5,3,8,15,5,3,8,15,26,21,12,21,5,3,8,15,5,3,8,15,18,15,13,5,15,15,19,3,1,18,14,15,22,5,13,2,5,18,9,14,4,9,1,14,15,22,5,13,2,5,18,5,3,8,15,18,15,13,5,15

The result above

> is the letter number in the English alphabet. (e.g.: 1 = A, 2 = B, etc.)

Translating this, we get:

> ALPHA
>  INDIA
>  TANGO
>  SIERRA
>  INDIA
>  XRAY
>  SIERRA
>  ECHO
>  VICTOR
>  ECHO
>  NOVEMBER
>  FOXTROT
>  INDIA
>  FOXTROT
>  ECHO
>  TANGO
>  ROMEO
>  ECHO
>  ECHO
>  ZULU
>  ECHO
>  ECHO
>  ROMEO
>  OSCAR
>  NOVEMBER
>  INDIA
>  NOVEMBER
>  ECHO
>  ROMEO

These are the

> Phonetic spellings of the English alphabet.

Which spells out the following:

> AIT SIX SEVEN FIFE TREE ZEERO NINER

Which are the

> Phonetic spellings of the numbers.

Giving us her phone number:

> 867-5309

Which, [pop-culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/867-5309/Jenny) tells us belongs to:

> Jenny

Comment: Not sure where you got the **.....** on the first line as I have no 5s until the 3rd...

Comment: I think I may have screwed something up in my copy/pasting efforts.

Comment: That would be my guess. It's OK though, you still got the right answer with all the right reasoning.

Comment: Redid the answer - I messed up the copy/paste right at the beginning, causing all the weirdness.

Comment: Can you explain why pop culture says that ? I didn't get it.

Comment: @user230452 It's a [song](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/867-5309/Jenny) by Tommy Tutone of the same name.

Comment: @Siyual : Appreciate your intelligence & patience to find answer to such a twisted puzzle.

Comment: Must be a different girl than the one from the song, she didn't write it on the wall!

Comment: @user230452 Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eND16kC79pw

Answer (score 34):

Alternative solution:

Her name is

> Alice

Bob quickly realized this because

> The message is clearly encrypted somehow, and Alice and Bob are the two names very commonly used in cryptography examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob

As for her phone number,

> Bob simply solved the 19 math equations as written, for example:
>  
>  1.4 - 2 - 2.2 - 1.4 - 2.3 - 2 - 2.2 - 1.4 - 1 - 4.2 - 2.2 - 3 - 2.2 - 2.2 - 1.4 - 4 - 1.2 - 2.2 - 1.4 - 4.1 - 2 - 2.2 - 4.1 - 2 - 2.2 - 4 - 1.2 - 2.2 - 1.4 - 2.3 - 5 - 2 - 2.2 - 1.4 - 2 - 2.2 - 1.4 - 4.1 - 2 - 2.2 - 2 - 3.2 - 2.2 - 1.4 - 5. = -103.1

Yielding the values:

> -103.1
>  -106.3
>  -68.4
>  -46.2
>  -18.2
>  -61
>  -187.2
>  -36
>  -37.4
>  -18.2
>  -18.2
>  -53.2
>  -18.2
>  -37.4
>  -34.2
>  -61
>  -90
>  -18.2
>  -37.4

Solving *that* as written yields:

> -1049.8

And then multiplying that

> by the square of the number of equations, 19, yields:
>
>  -3789778

A perfect 7 digits:

> 378-9778

Finally,

> The Jenny / 867-5309 "solution" was clearly an ingenious red herring.  What are the odds of the woman being named Jenny and actually having that number? :-)

Comment: This was not the answer the OP was looking for, but it's still very well done. +1

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a stretch to me :P

Comment: @dcfyk: Oh, absolutely it's a stretch. :-)  This was intended to be a silly answer, not a serious one!

Comment: Meh. I still think this is the correct answer. :P

Comment: I know Jon, I wasn't being serious either haha.

Answer (score 24):

Her name is

> Jenny

Because

> It's morse code. The number precedes each dot or dash, delimited by commas. The lines spell out the phonetic alphabet by providing the number for each letter (1=A, 2=B etc.). The actual message is "AIT SIX SEVEN..." and at that point I extrapolated the rest. Jenny, I got your number :-)

Comment: Correct. I was hoping it would withstand scrutiny a little longer but clearly the minds of the SE are far too strong for my puzzles haha.

Comment: Keep em coming! Had a lot of fun working on it.

Comment: @Siyual showed much better detail in their answer.

Comment: If you would like me to I can change the selected answer to his. Personally I'm choosing the one that posted first.

Comment: That is up to you. I probably only posted first because I wasn't as detailed. It's a good puzzle, and should have the best answer chosen (which in my opinion is @Siyual's)!

Comment: Alright, will do.

Answer (score 11):

The short way

> Jenny

1. To publish a telephone number invites crank calls, so many movies/stories use [a fictitious telephone numbers prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_(telephone_number)) 555.
2. None of lines replicate three in a row, suggesting that the number does not contain 555.  Posting a phone # on this site likely against site rules unless the number is *very* public.
3. OP [@dcfyj](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22684/dcfyj) lives in USA.
4. The problem implies the name is not explicit.
5. A popular U.S. [the 1981 song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/867-5309/Jenny) that meets the above that names the woman.

---

The harder way:

After seeing the pattern `2-2.2-` every 2nd/3rd pattern, I assumed it was a

> space/separator.

Then 10 remaining patterns `1.4-`, `1-4.`, `2.3-`, `2-2.2-`, `2-3.`, `3.2-`, `3-2.`, `4.1-`, `4-1.`, `5-`, `5.` were

> likely digits.

The only paired digits began with `1.4-`, `2.3-` and `2.3-` had fewer combinations leading to

> `1.4-`, `2.3-` are 1 and 2

Extending that to the other patterns lead to

> `3.2-` is 3, `4.1-` is 4, `5-` is 5, `1-4.` is 6  ....

Converting that letter code to A-Z

> 1 12 16 8 1    ALPHA
>  9 14 4 9 1     INDIGO
>  20 1 14 7 15   TANGO
>  ...

and applying [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet)

> AITSIXSEVENFIFETREEZEERONINER

or

> 867-5309

which leads above mentioned song.

Comment: i like that you don't know/didn't apply morse and still worked it out

Comment: @RozzA Somewhat red-faced as I am familiar with Morse code and did not see that code's pattern until after solving the puzzle.